# Unable to run Rviz and RTABMAP using SSH

Tags: ros, kinect, rviz, ros-kinetic, ssh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everyone,

I am a student of Habib University and I am working on an Autonomous Rescue Robot.
The project aims to develop an Autonomous Robot that can make an entire Map of an unknown site 'Autonomously' and simultaneously send live Mapping and Localization data to a remote PC.

I am using a RaspberryPi 3 in which I've installed Lubuntu and ROS Kinetic. The problem I am currently facing is that I can connect to the Pi using SSH but when I run the Rviz and Rtabmap commands, it gives me an error.

rosrun rviz rviz
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Aborted

Is there any other way I can run Rviz and Rtabmap on a remote PC and visualize the Mapping and Localization data?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285690/unable-to-run-rviz-and-rtabmap-using-ssh/) by [Raza](https://answers.ros.org/users/34181/raza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cesarhcq](https://answers.ros.org/users/40890/cesarhcq/) on 2019-04-15**:
Hello! Did you fix it? I am having the same problem. Could you explain if you fix it?
Thanks

**Comment by [Raza](https://answers.ros.org/users/34181/raza/) on 2019-04-17**:
No, we weren't able to fix it. We had to install and Run the ROS on a laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
if i understand correctly your pi hasn't any display device for running rviz i suggest you to use [ros network](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup) and run rviz in your pc

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2018-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0